# ArrayList assigned data in constructor is losing its data despite not being cleared anywhere

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm having a strange problem. I have a `RecyclerAdapter` that has two constructors. I use this same adapter to populate two `RecyclerViews` that I want to look the same but they differe slightly & they are in two different fragments. Hence the two constructors:

```
public FinderRecycleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = data;
    this.mContext = context;
    groupsHidden = new ArrayList<>();

}

public FinderRecycleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data, ArrayList<String> userEnteredWords) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = data;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.userEnteredWords = userEnteredWords;
    groupsHidden = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The second is where I am running into problems. Everything displays & runs. The `RecyclerView` will display a list of words. The user will have entered **some** of these words - all I am trying to do is change the color of the words that are in the list that the user has entered (this isn't the problem). these words are passed and assigned to an `ArrayList<string>` this is done successfully as can be seen here:

[image]

However, when it comes to changing the color of these words, doing this in `onBindViewHolder` this list is now empty:

[image]

despite not modifying this list anywhere else.

Here is all the usages of that list. Lines one 102-103 are the lines in the image above & line 43 is above in the constructor code.

[image]

Whats strange is `this.mData`(also an `ArrayList<string>`) is used everywhere `this.userEnteredWords` but `this.mData` retains its values.

Here is the whole `onBindViewHolder` code but most of what I think you need to see within `onBindViewHolder` is in the second image.

```
 // binds the data to the TextView in each row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String word = mData.get(position);
    holder.wordRow.setText(word);

    if (holder.wordRow.getText().toString().matches((".*\\d.*"))) {
        int checkHeaderNum = Integer.parseInt(holder.wordRow.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));

        holder.wordRow.setBackgroundColor(this.mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        holder.wordRow.setTextColor(this.mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        holder.wordRow.setTextSize(25);
        holder.wordRow.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.textview_rounded));
        if (this.groupsHidden.contains(checkHeaderNum)) {
            holder.wordRow.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_maximize_white_24dp, 0, R.drawable.ic_maximize_white_24dp, 0); //Inserts the maximizes symbol to the end of TextRow
        } else {
            holder.wordRow.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_minimize_white_24dp, 0, R.drawable.ic_minimize_white_24dp, 0); //Inserts the minimised symbol to the end of TextRow
        }
        holder.wordRow.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);

    } else {
        //Resets anything previously made as any attributes previously made will still hold unless reset here
        holder.wordRow.setBackgroundColor(this.mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        holder.wordRow.setTextColor(this.mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.browser_actions_text_color));
        holder.wordRow.setBackgroundResource(0);
        holder.wordRow.setTextSize(22);
        holder.wordRow.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.wordRow.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);

        //Highlighting the letters the user has given if a condition was set -  only for home fragment
        if (isCondition()) {
            int startingIndex = word.indexOf(getUsersLetterEntry());
            int endingIndex = getUsersLetterEntry().length() + startingIndex;

            final SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(word);
            str.setSpan(
                    new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.blue)), //Making selection colored
                    startingIndex,
                    endingIndex,
                    SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            );
            str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startingIndex, endingIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); //Making selection bold
            holder.wordRow.setText(str);
        }


        //Setting the user entered words for the letter game to blue. This is only populated if has been called from the LettersGame fragment
        if (this.userEnteredWords != null && this.userEnteredWords.size() > 0) {
            if (this.userEnteredWords.contains(holder.wordRow.getText().toString())) {
                holder.wordRow.setTextColor(this.mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                holder.wordRow.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            }
        }


    }
```

Am i missing something completely obvious? I haven't come across this before.

Comment: Your constructor doesn't copy data, it just keeps the exact same ArrayList that was passed in. So if that ArrayList, which is available outside your object, is modified later, the changes will be reflected in your object's ArrayList too, since they're the same object

Comment: That could lead me on the right path, I didn't think I was modifying this outside of that class but I will look over it and report back.

Comment: @user That lead me on the right path and solved it. I created new instances of the member variables and added all of the passed in list. Write an answer and I'll accept, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `Collections.unmodifiableList()` to safeguard yourself against unintended mutability of collections, and creating defensive copies of the lists you get?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I haven't but I'll look into it! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't copy data, it just keeps the exact same ArrayList that was passed in. So if that ArrayList, which is available outside your object, is modified later, the changes will be reflected in your object's ArrayList too, since they're the same object.

I'd suggest making a new `ArrayList` and then using `Collections.addAll`